# Pytest: Collecting items from upper level directories

Tags: python, directory, pytest

I have a directory as follows, where the testfiles are identical:

```
|- project/    
   |- test_dir2/
      |- <testfile> 
   |- tester/
      |- conftest.py
      |- pytest.ini
      |- test_dir1/
         |- <testfile>
```

I am trying to invoke pytest and source test files from the upper level directory, "test_dir2."

I am able to sucessfully invoke pytest and source the test files within test_dir1 with the following:
`[name@server:~/<path>/project/tester]$ pytest test_dir1/ --type Dev`

Output:

> platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
> rootdir: /<path>/project/tester
> collected 1 item
> test_dir1/<testfile>

Now, when trying to run tests in test_dir2 with a similar command:
`[name@server:~/<path>/project/tester]$ pytest ../test_dir2/ --type Dev`

> ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
> pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --type Dev
> inifile: None
> rootdir:  /<path>/project/

And now, just to try without the "--type" option:
`[name@server:~/<path>/project/tester]$ pytest ../test_dir2/`

> platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
> rootdir: /<path>/project
> collected 0 items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcame my issue by copying the original conftest and pasting it at my top level directory, next to my test directory. From there I could specify the root directory (where the original conftest and other tester files were).

Answer (score 0):

The way you are executing the tests is valid. Perhaps the problem is that the test discovery does not recognize your test filenames, class names or function names.

By default test files need to match `test_*.py` or `*_test.py`, classes - `Test*` and functions - `test*`

You can also configure a different match pattern in your `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
python_files = *_pytest.py
python_functions = mytest_*
python_classes = *Tests
```

More information about test discovery: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery